# Simplifying an algebraic expression to zero

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Mathematica seems unable to simplify the following elementary expression involving square roots (which equals zero) to zero. What is going on?

```
Simplify[5 Sqrt[6 - 2 Sqrt[5]] + Sqrt[5] (-4 + Sqrt[6 - 2 Sqrt[5]])]
```

Comment: `FullSimplify` or `5 Sqrt[6 - 2 Sqrt[5]] + Sqrt[5] (-4 + Sqrt[6 - 2 Sqrt[5]]) // 
  FunctionExpand // Simplify`

Answer (score 4):

[`RootReduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootReduce.html) is an amazing function that expresses [algebraic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number) as simplest-possible polynomial roots:

```
RootReduce[5 Sqrt[6 - 2 Sqrt[5]] + Sqrt[5] (-4 + Sqrt[6 - 2 Sqrt[5]])]
(*    0    *)
```

Of course, as @cvgmt says, `FullSimplify` works just as well (and may even call `RootReduce`).

Comment: Thanks. Still, it feels very wrong to me that "Simplify" doesn't deliver zero, out the box. Surely if the answer is zero, then that is what "Simplify" should output.

Comment: `Simplify` is a severely restricted function that predates `FullSimplify` by almost a decade. Don't expect too much from it.